# Downloading the file when clicking the other button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem on my codes, whenever i click the linkbutton(download) to download the uploaded file and i click another button still downloading the uploaded file and here's my code.

```
lblFile.Text = Issue.FileName;

        if (lblFile.Text != "")
        {
            trAttachedFile.Visible = true;
            lbtnDownload.PostBackUrl = "~/Download.aspx?file=" + lblFile.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            trAttachedFile.Visible = false;
        }
```

And here's the Download.aspx code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["file"]))
        {
            DownloadID = Request.QueryString["file"];
            if (StartDownload() == true)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Your download should start shortly";
            }
            else
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Download File does not exist";
            }
        }

private bool StartDownload()
    {
        if (DownloadID != "")
        {
            string downloadPath = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SubPic"].ToString() + DownloadID;
            FileInfo downloadFile = new FileInfo(downloadPath);

            if (downloadFile.Exists)
            {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + downloadFile.Name);
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", downloadFile.Length.ToString());
                Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                Response.WriteFile(downloadFile.FullName);
                Response.End();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And here's the linkbutton

```
<tr runat="server" id="trAttachedFile">
            <td>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="File Attachment:" />
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFile" />
                &nbsp;
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Download" ID="lbtnDownload" CssClass="lbtnDownload" />
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because when you use button's PostBackUrl property, it changes the form's PostBackUrl

either add some codes to change back the PostBackUrl to original one in your code some where, or in your case, you don't need a really post back url change, just try to use a hyperlink to navigate to your download url to start the download